# WPF DataTemplate create object

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate which Looks like the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <!-- ...Styles... -->
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource MyGridStyle}">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type1}">
                    <Label>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type2}">
                    <Label>
                        <!-- ... some other Settings as above -->
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now in the code I would like to create visible objects using this data template. I tried the following:

```
Type1 object1 = new Type1();
DataTemplate template = myDataTemplateFromAbove;
FrameworkElement visibleElement = template.loadContent() as FrameworkElement;
visibleElement.DataContext = object1;
```

The `visibleElement` is loaded and I can see ist children using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visibleElement, i)`. It Looks like the following:

```
 - Border
    - Grid
       - ContentPresenter
```

As you can see it doesn't load the actual Content of the template (the Label) which is based on a condition. Altough the Grid has Resources loaded (I can see them in the Debugger) they are not applied to the object.

So how do I properly load a visible object using a DataTemplate and based on a DataContext?

Comment: Why are you adding view elements in code rather than in xaml? That is not very good practice

Comment: @GordonAllocman Yes I know that it's not good practice, but for a special porpose where I want to influence the way how these elements are rendered. I think: everything that is possible in XAML must be possible in code too

Comment: The presenter may not bother to load the template for its content until it needs to. There's nothing in the code above that would require that to happen, as the top-level template's content is never added to anything else. In any case, there's not enough information here to know what the answer you're looking for is. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you are trying to do in code what you can do in XAML, be sure to also include an example of the XAML you are trying to emulate. I agree with @Gordon that your code-behind-based approach is probably not correct. But at the very least, if you want a good answer, it's important for us to understand why you are doing it this way.